# reduce is not giving right sum

Tags: javascript, lodash

My Object `groupBy.Food` looks like

```
[
Object
amount: "15.0"
category: Object
debit: true
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
amount: "10.0"
category: Object
debit: true
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
amount: "11.1"
category: Object
debit: true
__proto__: Object
]
```

All I want is `sum` of amount in each object. I am using [Lodash reduce](http://lodash.com/docs#reduce) as

```
var s = _.reduce(groupBy.Food, function(s, entry){
   return s + parseFloat(entry.amount);
});
```

When I see value of `s` I get

```
s
"[object Object]1011.1"
```

What is that I am not doing right here?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By default, [`reduce`](http://lodash.com/docs#reduce) starts out with the first two items in the list, so `s` will be the first item in the array and `entry` will be the second item the first time your function is called. Give it a value to start with:

```
var s = _.reduce(groupBy.Food, function(s, entry) {
    return s + parseFloat(entry.amount);
}, 0);
```

(`Array`’s `reduce` behaves the same way.)

Comment: This explains it. Thank you @minitech

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `_.sum(array)` or `_.sumBy(array, [iteratee=_.identity])` for summing up for both array and object. See below examples.

```
_.sum([4, 2, 8, 6]); // ➜ 20

var objects = [{ 'n': 4 }, { 'n': 2 }, { 'n': 8 }, { 'n': 6 }];
_.sumBy(objects, function(o) { return o.n; }); // ➜ 20
_.sumBy(objects, 'n');// ➜ 20
```